# How to get all occurances of group with regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

From code:

```py
myStr = "one two four five"
myPattern = r'\w*\s(two\s|three\s|four\s)*\w*'
matched = re.search(myPattern, myStr)

if matched:
    res = matched.group(1)
    print(res)
```

I get "four ", but I want to get ["two ", "four "]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all your surrounding word characters are optional, you can use re.findall and assert a whiteapace char to the left and match the trailing one:

```
(?<=\s)(?:two|three|four)\s
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RdZqGU/1)

```
import re

myStr = "one two four five"
pattern="(?<=\s)(?:two|three|four)\s"

print(re.findall(pattern, myStr))
```

Output

```
['two ', 'four ']
```